# Smoothing out a result set by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL I need to return a smooth set of results (i.e. one per day) from a dataset that contains 0-N records per day.

The result per day should be the most recent previous value even if that is not from the same day. For example:

Starting data:

```
Date:       Time:      Value
19/3/2014   10:01      5
19/3/2014   11:08      3
19/3/2014   17:19      6
20/3/2014   09:11      4
22/3/2014   14:01      5
```

Required output:

```
Date:       Value
19/3/2014   6
20/3/2014   4
21/3/2014   4
22/3/2014   5
```

Comment: What have you written so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: The solution will most likely depend on what specific database you are using, so you should add a tag for that to the question.

Comment: The Database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to complete the date range and fill in the missing dates (`21/3/2014` in you example). This can be done by either joining a calendar table if you have one, or by using a recursive common table expression to generate the complete sequence on the fly.

When you have the complete sequence of dates finding the max value for the date, or from the latest previous non-null row becomes easy. In this query I use a correlated subquery to do it.

```
with cte as (
    select min(date) date, max(date) max_date from your_table
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, date) date, max_date
    from cte
    where date < max_date
)

select 
    c.date, 
    (
     select top 1 max(value) from your_table 
     where date <= c.date group by date order by date desc
    ) value
from cte c
order by c.date;
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this works but try and let me know

```
select date, value from test where (time,date) in (select max(time),date from test group by date);
```